# React failing to parse a JSON object from server

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I'm running into this error: 

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 1`

when I pass a JSON object containing an array of JSON objects to my component. The object structure is:

`{ "arrayName": [{object},{object},{object}, etc...] }`

I've run the JSON through a validator and it comes up clean but my api call always returns the same error.

```
export const api = 'http://localhost:8000'

export const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept' : 'application/json',

}

export const getAll = () =>
    fetch(`${api}/480.json`, { headers })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data.events)
```

This is where it gets called in App.js:

```
componentDidMount() {
        eventsAPI.getAll().then((events) => {
            console.log(events)
            this.setState({ events })
        })
    }
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error, I know I'm sending a valid JSON object, is the way I'm receiving it wrong? I can see in the network tab of the dev tools that the correct format is being passed and received. I just don't know where exactly I've gone wrong. This is the response logged from the server. I can see the XHR response in dev-tools but it's a bit big to post here 25+ objects.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for how you're using `getAll`? It doesn't return anything at the moment

Comment: can you post an example (or a screenshot) of your returned data?

Comment: What line is the error throwing on?

Comment: Can you try not adding the Content-Type header? That is unnecessary for GET requests.

Comment: That did it! @andy729

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify `getAll` to actually return something. As it is a fetch, you can just return that, which will return the promise.

```
export const getAll = () =>
    return fetch(`${api}/480.json`, { headers })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data.events)
```

Now wherever you use `getAll` be sure to call `then`:

```
getAll().then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: I've added the where  my code for where the function is called.

Comment: @MichaelPorter See my answer. You need `return` before fetch

Comment: I made the suggested change and react throws an error. The arrow function doesn't like that syntax. I appreciate the help, I'll keep working on it.

Comment: The `return` statement is unnecessary. Arrow functions have implicit return